# Redshift Grant Statements Taking a very long time

Tags: amazon-redshift, database-permissions

I am running an SQL script called by workbench/J in CLI to execute about 15 grant statements. This takes well over 30 minutes. The data has not changed, and all other types of statements run at their regular speed. Workbench Build 119

Comment: please can you explain what / how you are running exactly? i dont understand what you mean by "SQL script called by workbench/J in CLI"

Comment: It is just a .sql file that has lines such as:

Comment: such as what?....

Comment: `grant select on table markets to user corporate' etc. I then use a batch file to call the workbench.exe 

The main thing is, I'm just executing grant statements with workbench/J and its taking forever

Comment: can you try using psql? same?

Comment: sorry psql? is that this? https://www.postgresql.org/

Comment: psql is the best way to run redshift in batch - not through workbench.exe! - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-from-psql.html

Comment: gotcha, thank you. Actually this issue has stopped. It plagued our processes for weeks and I guess it just stopped. I cannot identify any specific action that did so. Unsure how to close out this question with that conclusion though